# Element of a group, its order and inferring that it belongs to a subgroup generated by another element

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, subgroup-growth

As part of a larger proof, I want to make the following statement:

Let G be finite abelian group.

Let $g\in G$ such that the order of $g^{q}$ is $q^{e}$ where $e\geq1$ and q is prime.

Let $h\in G$ such that $h$ is a power of $g$.

Moreover, let $x_{0}$ be a solution to the Discrete Logarithm Problem applied to $g^{q^{e}}$ and $h^{q^{e}}$.

That is, $(g^{q^{e}})^{x_{0}}=h^{q^{e}}$.

Therefore, $(g^{q^{e}})^{x_{0}}=h^{q^{e}} \iff h^{q^{e}}.(g^{q^{e}})^{-x_{0}}=1\iff(h.g^{-x_{0}})^{q^{e}}=1$.

Now, can I say that $(h.g^{-x_{0}})\in<g^{q}>$?

Comment: No${}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: I am pretty sure I can, since this is part of the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm proof. I just don't know how.

Comment: Then you should say that $G$ is a finite abelian group since that information changes everything.

Comment: @jkbestami You need a lot more then $G$ just being a group to use the P-H algorithm.

Comment: You are totally right Levent, and I made the edit. I know that you need more for the P-H algorithm but I think I have everything else except for the justification of this claim.

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: I think that if I apply it to $<g^{q}>$ it tells me that every element $x\in<g^{q}>$ can be written as $n.g^{q}$, where does the order of $z$ come to play?

Comment: The claim still is not true. Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and take $g=(1,0)$. Now the order of $g^2=2\cdot g=(2,0)$ is $2$ but even though $(0,1)$ has order $2$ it is not an element of the subgroup generated by $(2,0)$.

Comment: You are right. I think I oversimplified my claim, I will try to re-edit it.

Comment: The claim is correct under the assumption that $G$ is a cyclic group of prime power order (or you can generalize to the groups of the form $G=H\times P$ where $P$ is a cyclic group of prime power order and $(|P|,|H|)=1$).

Comment: I went ahead with the edit without seeing your comment, sorry. But my problem is that $G$ is not a cyclic group of prime power order, however the subset generated by g is one. Would the claim still hold ?

Answer (score 0):

For a cyclic group $H$ of order $n$, it is a theorem that there exists a unique subgroup $K\leq H$ of order $d$ for every divisor $d$ of $n$. Notice that the subgroup generated by $g$ is cyclic of order $q^{e+1}$. Now $h\cdot g^{-x_0}$ has order at most $q^e$. Say $h\cdot g^{-x_0}$ has order $q^d$. Then this element lies in the unique subgroup of order $q^d$ which is necessarily generated by $g^{e+1-d}$. Hence $h\cdot g^{-x_0}\in \langle g^{e+1-d}\rangle\subseteq\langle g^q\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome, the key point is the so-called the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups. I believe that it is heavily used in cryptography.